# Can I just call such a subroutine which returns a value as if it returned `void`?

Tags: c

From Programming Language Pragmatics, by Scott:

> If the programmer wishes to call a subroutine that does return a
>   value, but the value is not needed in this particular case (all that
>   matters is the side effect[s]), then the return value in C can be
>   discarded by “casting” it to void:
>
> ```
> foo_index = insert_in_symbol_table(foo);
> ...
> (void) insert_in_symbol_table(bar);
> ```

Can I just call such a subroutine which returns a value as if it returned `void`?

```
insert_in_symbol_table(bar);
```

What syntax or semantics rules do I violate?

Thanks.

Comment: Your compiler will complain if it is told to.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams How do I tell gcc/clang/tcc to do that?

Comment: @PSkocik: `-Wunused-result`

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That doesn't do it. `-Wunused-result` should be on by default and it only warns for functions explicitly marked `__attribute__((__warn_unused_result__))`. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @PSkocik: The GCC man page says that `-Wno-unused-result` is the default.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Empirically, `-Wunsued-result` is on by default in `gcc` and `clang`. Interestingly I just learned that a `(void)` cast in clang (but not gcc) does silence the WUR warning, but since it doesn't in gcc, I still havea  used for my ignore macro.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't required to put the cast to void in. For example, the `printf` function returns a value (how many characters were written), but it's rare to see someone catch the return value or cast it to void.

A void cast is often a good idea if you're calling a function specifically for the side effects in a way that's unusual or counterintuitive and you want to explicitly signal to other people reading the code that yes, you know you're ignoring the return value, and that yes, that was intentional.

Answer (score 1):

You don't violate any rules. The reason why you would want to explicitly do that cast is to let the compiler or a static code analyzer know that you're ignoring the return value on purpose else they might complain about a discarded return value. The reason that code analyzers or a compiler might warn you about this is because usually when a function returns something it's considered information that should be checked/processed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find the `void` casting very useful.
As far as I understand, it's just as good as a comment, and it won't silence
warnings from `__attribute__((__warn_unused_result__))` functions (a `gcc/clang` extension).

I've been using an explicit ignore macro that does silence these (or to simply say I'm ignoring a return value).

```
/*Ignore macro ( NS == your libs namespace) */
#define NS_ign(Expr)  do{__attribute__((__unused__)) __typeof(Expr) NS_ign = Expr; }while(0)

/*example usage*/
#include <stdio.h>
__attribute__((__warn_unused_result__))
int Puts(char const *X) { return puts(X); }

int main()
{
    //puts returns an int -- no harm done if you silently ignore it
    puts("hello world"); 
    /*(void)Puts("hello world");*/  //(void) cast doesn't silence WUR
    NS_ign(Puts("hello world"));    //this does
}
```